# cloneNode issue with HTML5 nodes in IE

Tags: html

I am trying to clone an HTML node using cloneNode() method of browser's DOM API and even using Jquery clone() function. The API works perfectly fine with HTML tags, However i am facing some issues while using it with HTML5 tags like time e.g.

The issue is that following `<time>` tag content `<time class="storydate">April 7, 2010</time>` gets converted to: <:time class=storydate awpUniq="912">April 7, 2010. Although IE renders the original time node correctly then why such issue with the clone API.

And this issue isn't observed in FF/ chrome. Please give some clue how to avoid this

Comment: The colon indicates a namespace, are you using an XHTML doctype?  It all seems to work for me in IE8 with the HTML5 doctype.  Also, [this might be useful](http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript).

Answer (score 3):

Is this of any help? From the HTML5 Shiv issue list:

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/issues/detail?id=28

Links to

http://pastie.org/935834#49

solution seems to be:

```
// Issue: <HTML5_elements> become <:HTML5_elements> when element is cloneNode'd
// Solution: use an alternate cloneNode function, the default is broken and should not be used in IE anyway (for example: it should not clone events)

// Example of HTML5-safe element cloning
function html5_cloneNode(element) {
  var div = html5_createElement('div'); // create a HTML5-safe element

  div.innerHTML = element.outerHTML; // set HTML5-safe element's innerHTML as input element's outerHTML

  return div.firstChild; // return HTML5-safe element's first child, which is an outerHTML clone of the input element
} // critique: function could be written more cross-browser friendly?
```

Comment: This would work well for DOM elements, but i would loose data associated with DOM Nodes. i.e node.data("prop", value);